# How to remove a directory from root?

Tags: bash, permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, anaconda

I was trying to download anaconda3 on my WSL using the command `sudo bash Anaconda*-*-Linux-x86_64.sh` but the installation was taking a while so I decided to stop it using Ctrl+C, but later when I tried to re run the command I get:

ERROR: File or directory already exists: '/root/anaconda3'
If you want to update an existing installation, use the -u option.

So I tried to run:

```
conda create -n asl python=3.8.8
```

But then I got the error:
conda: command not found

then I tried to run:

```
sudo bash -u Anaconda*-*-Linux-x86_64.sh
```

But got the following error:
bash: Anaconda*-*-Linux-x86_64.sh: No such file or directory

So, I decided to remove anaconda3 using:

```
rm -r /root/anaconda3
```

rm: cannot remove '/root/anaconda3': Permission denied

Then I tried to cd into root but was getting permission denied, how can I find a work around this.

PS: I have tried to run Ubuntu as an admin and still am unable to cd into root.

Comment: Tip: www.tdlp.org has "Bash guides", these are "old" but still provide a good amount of relevant knowledge about `bash`, the most(?) common 'command line' interface.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, will check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Permission denied" means a different user owns it. You forgot to use `sudo`:

```
sudo rm -r /root/anaconda3
```

Comment: yes my friend you are right, thank you so much!! I am pretty new to Ubuntu still learning my way around it. I would have up voted the ans but I dont have enough reputation